# IE 11 uses my responsive design

Tags: css, mobile

My pages are in an ugly Responsive mode when I view them in IE11 but as expected in Chrome. Here's the code I'm using to render my screen size:

```
  @media screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
  #column {width: 75%;}
  #blue-nav{position: absolute;}
  #white-bar{display: block; }
  #footer-div {width: 100%;}
  #footer {width: 75%; position: relative}
  #body-left {float: left; width: 40%; height: auto;}
  #logo {position: relative;}
  #body-right {float: right; width: 60%; height: auto;}
  .breadcrumb {margin:0; padding: 0; padding-top: 50px;}
  #rectangle {  background: rgb(248,248,248);border-color: rgb(217,217,217);border-width: 1px;clear:both;  display: flex;}
  body {background-color:#f0f0f0;}
  #footer {display: block;} 
  #footer-table{display: table;}

}
```

And here are my headers:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

I'm not sure why they look so bad in IE. Additionally, my logo gets a link-box around it and my text goes off the screen.

Comment: BTW, I'm a long time lurker of SO, first time poster.

Comment: try adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` as your first header. 'cause that last thing you said sounds like an IE8 quirk

Answer (score 0):

@abluejelly was correct.  Adding

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

fixed it.

Comment: I'll formalize this one then, with a why.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is Internet Explorer mis-detecting that it needs to load the page in IE 8 legacy mode. This is generally caused by an arguably idiotic default setting that makes any int***ra***net site, by default, load in IE8 mode, the land of non-standards and missing features.

To fix it, you just need to tell IE to not do that, via adding this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

which tells IE that this is not an IE 8 document.

Note that this ***MUST*** be the **first** header sent (first tag in the `<head />` section), or else IE will ignore it.